# Hosting a web service in an Android application

Tags: android, web-services

Is there any way to host a web service from an Android application? I will be hosting RESTful services via WCF and would like to be able to "push" data to an Android app. I understand this could be done with polling but would like to try to avoid that. I was thinking if I could host a web service from the Android app, I would be able to call it from my server. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: To me, your question was a little unclear. do you want your device to react like a server or to react as a client?

Comment: Are you only going to be pushing to the android app when it is connected to a local network, or do you expect it to work when the phone/tablet is connected in the wild?  If so, regardless of if you can do have the app listen for post backs you will have network issues (Firewalls/Address Translation), that will prevent you from connecting directly back to it.

Comment: @Sheikh Aman - both. I want it to act as a client to call to the server but also as a server to allow my server push to the device.

Comment: @Doon - Local network would be fine for now as this is for an in house application.

Comment: @Sean: Use C2DM, Urban Airship, Xtify, or the equivalent to push data to an Android app.

Comment: It looks like I could use C2DM to do what I need. Will need to see how long it takes the Android app to receive the notification from when the server sends it, hopefully this isn't a very long.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cloud to Device Messaging` (C2DM) to push data from a server to the device. This will eliminate the need to keep polling a webserver for updated data.

Then, use normal web access methods to access a server's data on any particular event.

Good enough? or you need more assistance?

 Just revert.

Comment: C2DM definitely looks like it may suit my needs. Do you know if there is any way to use C2DM on an intranet with no connection to Google? I will have a server that the device connects to but may not have an internet connection. Thanks.

Comment: This is something I'll have to do some research for, since I am also not a lot into C2DM stuff.